# Button won't disable in Android

Tags: java, android, button

```
public void enableButton(){
      exitButton.setEnabled(true);
}
public void disableButton(){
      exitButton.setEnabled(false);
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_page);
    InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
    FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(4);
    initializeEverything();
    text1.setFilters(FilterArray);
    text2.setFilters(FilterArray);
    text3.setFilters(FilterArray);
    text4.setFilters(FilterArray);
    text5.setFilters(FilterArray);

    final TextView textfinal = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.finaltext);


    TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
          textfinal.setText(calculateTotal());
          if(Double.parseDouble(textfinal.getText().toString())>100)
              textfinal.setTextColor(Color.RED);
              disableButton();
              Log.i("yo","gray this out");
          if(Double.parseDouble(textfinal.getText().toString())<100)
              textfinal.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
              enableButton();
      }

      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
      }

      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
              int count) {

      }
    };
    text1.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    text2.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    text3.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    text4.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    text5.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

I have a problem graying out exitButton. in initializeEverything(), I set exitButton.setEnabled(false) and it is grayed out in the beginning. After i enter some a numeric value under 100 to the editTexts(text1, text2 ...) The button becomes enabled. But when i exceed 100, it should be disabled again, but it stays enabled. the Logcat message "gray this shit out" is sent so I know the textWatcher is working correctly, I'm not sure why the button won't disable.

Comment: your code will crash when edit text is empty,because it can't parse null values. So check condition before executing the logic

Comment: I have if statements in the data-acquiring methods that check for null values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is with these lines

```
if(Double.parseDouble(textfinal.getText().toString())>100)
          textfinal.setTextColor(Color.RED);
          disableButton();
          Log.i("yo","gray this out");
 if(Double.parseDouble(textfinal.getText().toString())<100)
          textfinal.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
          enableButton();
```

Please note that only one line is attached to `if` in case you don't use brackets. Replace these lines  like this:

```
if(Double.parseDouble(textfinal.getText().toString())>100){
          textfinal.setTextColor(Color.RED);
          disableButton();
          Log.i("yo","gray this out");
}else if(Double.parseDouble(textfinal.getText().toString())<100){
          textfinal.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
          enableButton();
}
```